# Xamarin C# for Android : Searching for an App and path

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-package-managers

GOAL : I need to find if an app is installed on a device AND find it's path..

I see using `PackageManager`, you can do this in general but I would like to refine it.

I know if you use `com.google.chrome` you can find chrome explorer installed,
but this fails when you look simply for `Chrome`.

On some devices `Chrome` (and other apps, like `Opera`, `Mini`,etc) is not installed as `com.google.chrome`.

So how would one find an app without the `com.google` and just use `Chrome` as the search criteria ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, just combine `PackageManager` and `ApplicationInfo`, and then check if app name contain your search string. Here is some example code:

```
    var searchQuery = "chrome";
    var flag = PackageInfoFlags.Activities;
    var apps = PackageManager.GetInstalledApplications(flag);
    foreach(var app in apps)
    {
        try
        {
            var appInfo = PackageManager.GetApplicationInfo(app.PackageName, 0);
            var appLabel = PackageManager.GetApplicationLabel(appInfo);
            if (appLabel.ToLower().Contains(searchQuery.ToLower()))
            {
                var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.SetTitle("Found it!");
                builder.SetMessage(appLabel + " installed at: " + app.SourceDir);
                builder.Show();
            }
        }
        catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) { continue; }
    }
```

Comment: Brilliant !! .. So clean, so compact.. Thank you for sharing your knowledge !!